# Publication issue of a journal article in Elsevier

Tags: publications, elsevier

Recently, an article of mine got accepted in an Elsevier Journal. Since it was my first publication, I was not very much aware of the whole publication procedure. After acceptance of the paper, I got a link sent for gallery proof. At this stage, I found many grammatical mistakes in the paper, which I should have corrected during the revision stage. I have to agree that I was late regarding this matter. Yet, I incorporated all the extensive corrections and sent back the proof. The journal manager was helpful. He sent me a pdf file with all the corrections incorporated and asked me to approve the revised proof, which I did. Recently, I contacted Elsevier's customer support, whereby I got to know that the paper is in type-setting. It made me a bit confused because the pdf file I got from the journal manager was already corrected and type-setted.

So my question is how could be the paper in the typesetting stage if I have got a prepared pdf file of the revised proof for approval from the journal manager!! If anyone of you is familiar with this scenario, I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Nothing unusual is happening.

Comment: And it is quite normal to find typos in revised proof as well. At least is why you have received one. Take it as a final check opportunity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If Elsevier customer support is the same person as the journal manager, this would be weird. But there's a very good chance that they aren't the same person. Elsevier customer support is likely looking at a high-level overview of what the status is, and doesn't know the details. The journal manager would know it's the 2nd typesetting stage, but presumably the status is still reported as "typesetting" (which is, after all, what it is) and therefore also what Elsevier customer service tells you.

If you're already in contact with the journal manager, ask him/her for the status, not customer support.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.